# Does openssl s_server support LDAP starttls fucntionality?

Tags: openssl, ldap

I am trying to run a sanity test on my LDAP client starttls functionality. Aim is to test different TLS protocols with different ciphers (Just the starttls and tls handshake. Nothing related to actual LDAP authentication). I really dont want to change ciphers or TLS protocols on windows AD or openldap to test this. So i was wondering if openssl s_server support LDAP starttls fucntionality

From openssl documentation, i found that s_client has starttls functionality but nothing is mentioned in s_server.

I tried this on OpenSSL 1.1.1c. Below error is thrown, once starttls is recieved from ldap client.

```
[root@1234]# openssl s_server -accept 389 -cert rsyslog_cert.pem  -CAfile cachain.pem -key rsyslog_key.pem
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT

ERROR
140311741196096:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
^C
[root@1234]#
```

Am i doing something wrong?
Is there any other easier way to achieve this?

Comment: No, s_server does not support this.

Comment: Thanks @MattCaswell. Do you suggest any other way of doing this?

Comment: I have no suggestions - sorry.

Comment: Use one of the OpenLDAP utilities. They should work with any LDAP server.